# data.table:last fails on date vectors

Tags: r, data.table

`last` does not work on vectors of dates:

```
library(data.table)
f <- c("2014-11-10","2014-11-11")
last(f)
[1] "2014-11-11"
last(as.Date(f))
Error in last(as.Date(f)) : 
  data.table::last is trying to defer to xts::last because either x is not a vector, list, data.frame or data.table, or parameters such as 'n' or 'keep' have been provided as well. But xts hasn't been loaded.
```

the "helpful" message promised by `?last` says that the argument is not a vector (it is!) and requires a package `xts` which I don't know about.

what is going on?

Comment: `as.Date(last(f))` ?

Comment: @konvas: turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it, see, however, [How come as.Date affects is.vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847171/how-come-as-date-affects-is-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting from comments above, `is.vector(as.Date(f))` is `FALSE`, so it is not a vector. You need to first load `xts` using `library(xts)` and then load `data.table` and your code should work (since then data.table will be able to call `xts::last` on the `Date` object).