# How come as.Date affects is.vector?

Tags: r, date, vector

I cannot understand this:

```
f <- c("2014-11-10","2014-11-11")
is.vector(f)
[1] TRUE
is.vector(as.Date(f))
[1] FALSE     <------------- WTF?!!!
str(as.Date(f))
 Date[1:2], format: "2014-11-10" "2014-11-11"
str(f)
 chr [1:2] "2014-11-10" "2014-11-11"
```

why isn't `as.Date(f)` a vector?!

Comment: In the description of `?is.vector`: "`is.vector` returns `TRUE` if `x` is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes _other than names_.  It returns `FALSE` otherwise." `attributes(as.Date(f))` contains something other than "names".

Comment: See also the `is.object` function. In a sense, every object in R is an object, but only some objects are objects.

Comment: @nicola that sounds like a `fortunes::fortune`